# Flash does not work on Firefox in Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: firefox, lubuntu, flash

I have installed Lubuntu 14.04 but Flash isn't working correctly with Firefox 28.0. Viewing videos in YouTube, using the Spotify web client and yes.fm all do no work.

I can see that the addon is working fine: `shockwave flash version 11.2.202.350`

My system:

- Processor        : Pentium III (Coppermine)
- Memory       : 507MB (241MB used)
- Operating System     : (Lubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr)

Answer (score 1):

the up-to-date adobe flash player needs SSE2 CPU support to work correctly. According to wikipedia you processor does not have.

Source. Getting flashplayer to work on firefox  Athlon XP  lubuntu machine I have this problem. The solution is to get older versions of the libflashplayer.so file. Steps to fix:

- make sure flashplugin-installer package is installed.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
  ```
- download http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_10.0.45.2.orig.tar.gz
- extract libflashplayer.so from this file to home directory.

  ```
  tar -xvzf adobe-flashplugin_10.0.45.2.orig.tar.gz -C ~/

  mv adobe-flashplugin-10.0.45.2.orig/libflashplayer.so ~/
  ```
- copy downloaded libflashplayer.so in home directory to this folder:

  ```
  sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so
  ```
- close firefox and reopen, so that new flashplayer will be used. flash should now work (for firefox).

Problems with this is using outdated flashplayer will have security vulnerabilities so only use for sites you can trust. Also running updates on your system will mean having to repeat last copy command.

Answer (score 0):

Latest Flash version is 13, while the last linux version that works with Firefox is 11.2.

To have latest Flash, the most simple solution is installing [Google Chrome](http://google.com/chrome) which includes Flash version 13. Just download the `deb` for your system (32 bit) and do in a terminal `sudo dpkg -i google*.deb` in the folder where you downloaded the `deb` file or open the `deb` with the default software manager.

Comment: It seems that it is a bug for 32 bits  systems. I solved the question with the [link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/964567#answer-459471)  via liberforce but I also  will try your suggestion thanks! Download that libgcflashplayer.so file, rename it into libflashplayer.so, and put it in your /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins directory.

Comment: 2 things: The latest version 16, also the installing Chrome will install flash for chrome only. @user273159 - You can add your own answer with a solutuon if you found something that works

Comment: You don't need flash to watch youtube any more.

Answer (score -2):

I just did an update today ( 12th of September ) and I can watch youtube without troubles, I was having the same issue as you before.

Hope this helps !

Comment: What/How did you update?

Comment: Everything. System update.